# Transaction receipt can be missing for mined transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, receipts

ETH Node: Geth

I am subscribing to new blocks, check each block & add transactions related to my node to database.
Before adding i check if transaction have `receipt` and the have `gasPrice` or not.

my question is , is it possible for a mined transaction to not have transaction receipt or empty `gasPrice`  when its mined or to be specific immediately after node receives the transaction.

Any guidance is much appreciated.